# Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Constructor' of undefined bootstrap-popover.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'd like to use twitter bootstrap manually, on my rails project.
But I've got this error, and some functions of bootstrap don't work.

If you help me, I appreciate it. Thank you.

**Errors on Console**

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Constructor' of undefined     bootstrap-popover.js:38
>   (anonymous function)     bootstrap-popover.js:38
>   (anonymous function)     bootstrap-popover.js:115

**app/view/app/index.html.erb**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "bootstrap" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "bootstrap-responsive" %>

<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "bootstrap" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "bootstrap-transition" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "bootstrap-alert" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "bootstrap-modal" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "bootstrap-dropdown" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "bootstrap-scrollspy" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "bootstrap-tab" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "bootstrap-tooltip" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "bootstrap-popover" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "bootstrap-button" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "bootstrap-collapse" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "bootstrap-carousel" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "bootstrap-typeahead" %>

<!-- as example, which doesn't work, somehow  -->
<i class="icon-search icon-home"></i>
```

I believe everything necessary js and css files are in

- ./app/assets/images
- ./app/assets/javascripts
- ./app/assets/stylesheets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to add asset files ( like `.js` , `.css` or images ) in Rails >3 , you should use manifest files : application.js , application.css . After you copy sources in their directories , you should make declarations like this :

```
application.js :

//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-responcive
//= require tree .
```

and in application.css:

```
*= require_self
*= require bootstrap
*= require_tree .
```

It makes useless including  `<%= javascript_include_tag %> in your views .

Comment: To clear up why it worked; by having "require tree ." AFTER the others you ensure you include your bootstrap files in the right order. Leaving it up to filenames will load some bootstrap files in the wrong order e.g. popover before tooltip.