# Twitter Bootstrap Popover not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, syntax-error

I have the tooltip for bootstrap working, but anytime I try and initiate the popover instead I get the error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined** or **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Constructor' of undefined** with the following code

```
 Popover.prototype = $.extend({}, $.fn.tooltip.Constructor.prototype, {

    constructor: Popover

  , setContent: function () {
      var $tip = this.tip()
        , title = this.getTitle()
        , content = this.getContent()

      $tip.find('.popover-title')[this.options.html ? 'html' : 'text'](title)
      $tip.find('.popover-content')[this.options.html ? 'html' : 'text'](content)

      $tip.removeClass('fade top bottom left right in')
    }
```

I am unclear of the hiccup, because I did see it working previously. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Unfortunately, the widget js for bootstrap is not hosted. I tried to start it at least. http://jsfiddle.net/ZrL2q/3/

Comment: Have you seen this post about extending Object.prototype?  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955124/adding-methods-to-object-prototype-causes-an-error-when-twitter-bootstrap-modal]

Comment: @crazymatt so a previous js I'm using is breaking? I'm not doing anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: Its hard to say without seeing what code you are using. I suggest re-downloading BootStrap and getting it to work without modifying any of the code. If it doesnt work then your configuration is not set up correctly. If it does work then its probably a conflicting issue with the code you are trying to integrate it with.

Comment: Use https://github.com/Tavicu/bootstrap-confirmation if you want it on bootstrap 3.x.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue and was able to fix it with the help of Paul Watson's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121509/error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-constructor-of-undefined-boots#comment21377697_14121775)

Make sure bootstrap-tooltip.js is included *before* bootstrap-popover.js

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your call in a `$(document).ready()` block

ie:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tipsPop').tooltip();
});
```

Comment: yeah, that's not the issue. it's wrapped, i just took a piece of a long project.